# How can i convert Protocol string to Spymemcached Protocol enum using Java Reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I have a Java 5 application that uses Spymemcached and am having a problem when I want to convert the Protocol string to Enum object. Let's take a look into the following:

1. The enum Protocol is in ConnectionFactoryBuilder class.

```
package net.spy.memcached;

...

public class ConnectionFactoryBuilder {

    public enum Protocol {
        TEXT, BINARY

        private Protocol() {
            // compiled code
        }
    }
```

2. Now I need to convert string "TEXT" or "BINARY" to the above ConnectionFactoryBuilder.Protocol enum. I tried the following code but nothing works.

```
package mypackage;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String protocolString = "TEXT";

        // code 1:
        String protocolClassName1 = "net.spy.memcached.ConnectionFactoryBuilder.Protocol";
        Class protocolType1 = Class.forName(protocolClassName1); 
        // The above line throws: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.spy.memcached.ConnectionFactoryBuilder.Protocol
        Object protocolEnumObject1 = Enum.valueOf(protocolType1, protocolString);


        // code 2:
        Class connectionFactoryBuilderClass2 = Class.forName("net.spy.memcached.ConnectionFactoryBuilder");
        Field protocolField2 = null;
        for (Field f : connectionFactoryBuilderClass2.getDeclaredFields()) {
            System.out.print(f.getName() + ", ");
            if (f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Protocol")) {
                protocolField2 = f;
            }
        }
        Class protocolType2 = protocolField2.getType();
        Object protocolEnumObject2 = Enum.valueOf(protocolType2, protocolString);
        // In this approach, i can not get protocol field in that ConnectionFactoryBuilder class, here are output of getDeclaredFields():
        // opQueueFactory, readQueueFactory, writeQueueFactory, transcoder, failureMode, 
        // initialObservers, opFact, locator, opTimeout, isDaemon, shouldOptimize, useNagle, 
        // maxReconnectDelay, readBufSize, hashAlg, authDescriptor, opQueueMaxBlockTime, 
        // timeoutExceptionThreshold, metricType, collector, executorService, authWaitTime, $assertionsDisabled, 

    }

}
```

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Why reflection? Why not just use `valueOf()`?

Comment: Because my app is written in Java 5, but that Spymemcached supports Java 6+

Comment: Then you can't use it unless you upgrade your app to Java 6 (which should be straightforward btw). Reflection ain't gonna solve anything here.

Comment: No guy, that Spymemcached feature in my app will be supported for Java6+ users only. I need to compile my app in Java 5 for supporting old system, that is why I need to use reflection for Java6+ features

Comment: If that feature is for Java 6 it's for a reason: the bytecode is Java 6, and you can't run it with Java 5. Again reflection is not going to solve your problem, but be my guest. In any case make your question more clear, currently you're not explaining your problem correctly.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand you, my app is still working fine here. The above Protocol is just new support for current spymemcached feature in the next version of my app

Comment: so what i need your help is how to convert Protocol string to Enum object using Reflection as what i wrote above, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found out how to solve this. Basically the enum Protocol is nested class in the ConnectionFactoryBuilder, therefore I need to use `$` to locate it.

Here is solved code:

```
package mypackage;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String protocolString = "TEXT";

        // code 1:
        // OLD: String protocolClassName1 = "net.spy.memcached.ConnectionFactoryBuilder.Protocol";
        String protocolClassName1 = "net.spy.memcached.ConnectionFactoryBuilder$Protocol";
        Class protocolType1 = Class.forName(protocolClassName1); 
        Object protocolEnumObject1 = Enum.valueOf(protocolType1, protocolString);

        System.out.println(protocolEnumObject1.getClass());
        // class net.spy.memcached.ConnectionFactoryBuilder$Protocol

    }

}
```